# Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.ExceptionUtils.preload()V

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, pcfdev

I am using JDk 1.8 and Spring boot 2.0.8, app is working fine in local laptop however once deploy on PCF its start complain

> Unable to start web server; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.ExceptionUtils.preload()V

Dependancy Tree:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.19:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.14.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.0.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.37:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.37:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.37:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] +- net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:jar:4.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.hive:hive-jdbc:jar:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.hive:hive-common:jar:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.hive:hive-classification:jar:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.hive:hive-storage-api:jar:2.3.0.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.7:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.orc:orc-core:jar:1.5.1.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.orc:orc-shims:jar:1.5.1.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- io.airlift:aircompressor:jar:0.10:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs:jar:3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util-ajax:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.19:compile
[INFO]    |  |     |  \- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |     \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.19:compile
[INFO]    |  +- jline:jline:jar:2.14.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-rewrite:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
[INFO]    |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- net.sf.jpam:jpam:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.tdunning:json:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO]    |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.2.6:compile
[INFO]    |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jvm:jar:3.2.6:compile
[INFO]    |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-json:jar:3.2.6:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.github.joshelser:dropwizard-metrics-hadoop-metrics2-reporter:jar:0.1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:jar:3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |     |  \- jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.8:system
[INFO]    |  |     +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:runtime
[INFO]    |  |     +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:jar:1.19:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- org.apache.commons:commons-configuration2:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- com.google.re2j:re2j:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.54:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- org.apache.kerby:kerb-simplekdc:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |     |  +- org.apache.kerby:kerb-client:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |     |  |  +- org.apache.kerby:kerby-config:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |     |  |  +- org.apache.kerby:kerb-core:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |     |  |  |  \- org.apache.kerby:kerby-pkix:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |     |  |  |     +- org.apache.kerby:kerby-asn1:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |     |  |  |     \- org.apache.kerby:kerby-util:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |     |  |  +- org.apache.kerby:kerb-common:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |     |  |  |  \- org.apache.kerby:kerb-crypto:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |     |  |  +- org.apache.kerby:kerb-util:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |     |  |  \- org.apache.kerby:token-provider:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |     |  |     \- com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:jar:3.10:compile
[INFO]    |  |     |  |        +- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |     |  |        +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO]    |  |     |  |        |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |     |  |        \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.52:compile
[INFO]    |  |     |  \- org.apache.kerby:kerb-admin:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |     |     +- org.apache.kerby:kerb-server:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |     |     |  \- org.apache.kerby:kerb-identity:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |     |     \- org.apache.kerby:kerby-xdr:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile
[INFO]    |  |     \- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO]    |  \- javolution:javolution:jar:5.5.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.hive:hive-service:jar:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.hive:hive-llap-server:jar:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.hive:hive-llap-common:jar:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.hive:hive-llap-client:jar:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.apache.curator:apache-curator:pom:2.12.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.hive:hive-llap-tez:jar:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.1.31.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.hive:hive-llap-common:test-jar:tests:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-hadoop2-compat:jar:2.0.2.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-metrics:jar:2.0.2.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-metrics-api:jar:2.0.2.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:jar:3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |     +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-client:jar:3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |     \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs-client:jar:3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |        \- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |           \- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.6.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-server:jar:2.0.2.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-http:jar:2.0.2.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.5.0-b42:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-procedure:jar:2.0.2.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-zookeeper:jar:2.0.2.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-replication:jar:2.0.2.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.web:javax.servlet.jsp:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  |  \- org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- org.apache.htrace:htrace-core:jar:3.2.0-incubating:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- com.lmax:disruptor:jar:3.3.6:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-distcp:jar:3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:jar:3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |     \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient:jar:3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |        \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-common:jar:3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-mapreduce:jar:2.0.2.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-common:jar:2.0.2.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- com.github.stephenc.findbugs:findbugs-annotations:jar:1.3.9-1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.apache.hbase:hbase-hadoop-compat:jar:2.0.2.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  +- javax.servlet.jsp:javax.servlet.jsp-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-runner:jar:9.3.25.v20180904:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:6.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:7.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |     +- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:7.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:7.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jaas:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-server:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-servlet:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:apache-jsp:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.toolchain:jetty-schemas:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:apache-jstl:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- org.apache.taglibs:taglibs-standard-spec:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO]    |  |     \- org.apache.taglibs:taglibs-standard-impl:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.thrift:libfb303:jar:0.9.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-recipes:jar:2.12.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.jamon:jamon-runtime:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.hive:hive-serde:jar:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.arrow:arrow-vector:jar:0.8.0.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.arrow:arrow-format:jar:0.8.0.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.arrow:arrow-memory:jar:0.8.0.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.31.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.31.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.carrotsearch:hppc:jar:0.7.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.vlkan:flatbuffers:jar:1.2.0-3f79e055:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.7.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.8.8:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.0.4.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.parquet:parquet-hadoop-bundle:jar:1.10.0.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.hive:hive-metastore:jar:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.hive:hive-standalone-metastore:jar:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.datanucleus:datanucleus-api-jdo:jar:4.2.4:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.datanucleus:datanucleus-core:jar:4.1.17:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.datanucleus:datanucleus-rdbms:jar:4.1.19:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.datanucleus:javax.jdo:jar:3.2.0-m3:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- javax.transaction:transaction-api:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- sqlline:sqlline:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:16.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:jar:2.0.2.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.hbase.thirdparty:hbase-shaded-protobuf:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-protocol-shaded:jar:2.0.2.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-protocol:jar:2.0.2.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |     \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:jar:3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bundle:jar:1.11.271:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.hbase.thirdparty:hbase-shaded-miscellaneous:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.hbase.thirdparty:hbase-shaded-netty:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.htrace:htrace-core4:jar:4.2.0-incubating:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.jruby.jcodings:jcodings:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.jruby.joni:joni:jar:2.1.11:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-crypto:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.apache.yetus:audience-annotations:jar:0.5.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.jolbox:bonecp:jar:0.8.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:2.7.9:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.derby:derby:jar:10.14.2.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO]    |  +- javax.jdo:jdo-api:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.5.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- co.cask.tephra:tephra-api:jar:0.6.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- co.cask.tephra:tephra-core:jar:0.6.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.5:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-assistedinject:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.twill:twill-common:jar:0.6.0-incubating:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.twill:twill-core:jar:0.6.0-incubating:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.apache.twill:twill-api:jar:0.6.0-incubating:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.twill:twill-discovery-api:jar:0.6.0-incubating:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.twill:twill-discovery-core:jar:0.6.0-incubating:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.apache.twill:twill-zookeeper:jar:0.6.0-incubating:compile
[INFO]    |  \- co.cask.tephra:tephra-hbase-compat-1.0:jar:0.6.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.hive:hive-shims:jar:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.hive.shims:hive-shims-common:jar:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.hive.shims:hive-shims-0.23:jar:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78:runtime
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager:jar:3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78:runtime
[INFO]    |  |     +- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-servlet:jar:4.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-guice:jar:1.19:compile
[INFO]    |  |     |  \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-common:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |     |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO]    |  |     |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO]    |  |     |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-api:jar:3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |     |  \- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.19:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-server-common:jar:3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78:runtime
[INFO]    |  |     |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-registry:jar:3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78:runtime
[INFO]    |  |     |  |  +- commons-daemon:commons-daemon:jar:1.0.13:runtime
[INFO]    |  |     |  |  \- dnsjava:dnsjava:jar:2.1.7:runtime
[INFO]    |  |     |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jcache_1.0_spec:jar:1.0-alpha-1:runtime
[INFO]    |  |     |  +- org.ehcache:ehcache:jar:3.5.3:runtime
[INFO]    |  |     |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP-java7:jar:2.4.12:runtime
[INFO]    |  |     |  \- com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:jar:6.2.2.jre8:runtime
[INFO]    |  |     +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice:jar:3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78:runtime
[INFO]    |  |     |  +- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.0:runtime
[INFO]    |  |     |  \- de.ruedigermoeller:fst:jar:2.50:runtime
[INFO]    |  |     |     \- com.cedarsoftware:java-util:jar:1.9.0:runtime
[INFO]    |  |     |        \- com.cedarsoftware:json-io:jar:2.5.1:runtime
[INFO]    |  |     +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy:jar:3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78:runtime
[INFO]    |  |     \- org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni-all:jar:1.8:runtime
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.hive.shims:hive-shims-scheduler:jar:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78:runtime
[INFO]    +- org.apache.hive:hive-service-rpc:jar:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.6:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.10:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.thrift:libthrift:jar:0.9.3:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.6.3.1.0.0-78:compile
[INFO]    |  \- io.netty:netty:jar:3.10.5.Final:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.curator:curator-framework:jar:2.12.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.curator:curator-client:jar:2.12.0:compile
[INFO]    \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

PCF logs :

```
[ERR] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.ExceptionUtils.preload()V
[ERR] at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.<init>(Tomcat.java:160)
[ERR] at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:160)
[ERR] at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181)
[ERR] at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:154)
[APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] ... 16 more
```

I have tried diffrent springboot version and fllowing properties with diffrent tomcat version.

```
<properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
            <tomcat.version>8.5.37</tomcat.version>
</properties>
```

Also tried to exclude tomcat in web and added from external dependency but nothing is working on pcf

Comment: Can you start your app on PCF with `-verbose:class`. That will show from where `org.apache.tomcat.util.ExceptionUtils` is being loaded. Alternatively, there should be some failure analysis in the logs that show similar details.

Comment: Since you're saying it works fine locally, can you also include your full `cf push` command, a manifest.yml (if you have one) and also the output of staging so we can see what the buildpack is doing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your dependencies are missing the following:

```xml
<dependency> 
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId> 
   <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId> 
   <version>8.5.37</version> 
</dependency>
```

Make sure to add it into your `pom.xml`.